# Prove linear dependency of $\{\vec u,\vec v, \vec w\}$ if $\{\vec u,\vec v\}$, $\{\vec v,\vec w\}$ and $\{\vec u,\vec w\}$ are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}$ are vectors of the subspace $V$ and $\{\vec{u},\vec{v}\}$, $\{\vec{v},\vec{w}\}$ and $\{\vec{u},\vec{w}\}$ are linearly independent. Is $\{\vec{u},\vec{v}, \vec{w}\}$ linearly independent?

Comment: In proper MathJax usage, the $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ are inside of MathJax, not outside of it, thus: $$ \{\vec{u},\vec{v}, \vec{w}\} $$ I edited the question accordingly. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are linearly dependent by counterexample:
Clearly $\{(1,0);(0,1)\}$, $\{(1,0); (1,1)\}$ and $\{(0,1); (1,1)\}$ are all linearly independent but clearly $\{(1,0);(0,1);(1,1)\}$ are not linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily.

Consider $\vec{u}=\langle1,1,0\rangle$, $\vec{v}=\langle1,0,1\rangle$, and $\vec{w}=\langle0,1,-1\rangle$.

You can immediately see that each pair of vectors must be linearly independent (each has a $0$ component that is non-zero in the others); but, $\vec{u}-\vec{v}=\vec{w}$.